# c OpenCV; How to convert 2-dimension array to IplImage?

Tags: c, opencv, iplimage

I'm using the c-api and am new to OpenCV.

Assume I have 2-dimension array including; red[][], green[][], blue[][]. I would like to convert 3 of 2-d array to IplImage and save it to .png file. However, from my system I cannot use CvMat.

Could you help me solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: IplImage is the outdated c-api, not c++. avoid it.

Comment: thank you for more information, but I cannot control the system that I use it now.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C++, use C++ API:

```
cv::Mat image = cv::Mat::zeros(w,h, CV_8UC3);
for(int x=0;x<w;x++)
   for(int y=0;y<h;y++)
        image.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x) = cv::Vec3b(red[x][y], blue[x][y], green[x][y]);
cv::imwrite("image.png", image);
```

But if you really want to have c-api, conversion from cv::Mat to IplImage works:

```
IplImage *frameConverted = new IplImage(image);
```

Remember about releasing memory if you don't need frameConverted anymore.

Comment: Thank your for your code, but I got this message **"error: no matching function for call to ‘cv::Mat::zeros(int&, int&)’"** when I compile it. Maybe my system install the old version of OpencV. I cannot control the system by myself. Could you suggest the other way without using Mat.

Comment: I forgot about the third param, which is type of pixel. In our case, we have 3 unsigned chars and that is exactly what CV_8UC3 means (CV_{bits per pixel}{U|S|F}{channels} where U - unsigned, S - signed, F - float

Comment: I added conversion to IplImage. Even if you don;t want to use C++ api and you have opencv ver. > 2.0 you have to have c++ api so you can use it anyway.